# Mongo deleting a document using an object as a value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Hello I am having issues deleting a document from MongoDb using an object

here is what I mean

```
const deleteTrimByName = function (db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  const collection = db.collection(documentName)
  // Insert some documents
  console.log(trimNameToDelete)
  collection.deleteOne({Video_trim: trimNameToDelete}, function (err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null)
    assert.equal(1, result.result.n)
    console.log('Removed the document')
    callback(result)
  })
  fs.unlink('./public/videos/cut-videos/' + documentName + '/' + trimNameToDelete.trimName + '.mp4', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('failed to delete local image:' + err)
    } else {
      console.log('successfully deleted local image')
    }
  })
}
```

where trimNameToDelete evaluates to

```
{"trimName":"cut2","startTime":"00:00:05","endTime":"00:00:15"}
```

and the mongo document appears as this in the shell

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5abe67897a9b9e0933c64acd"), "Video_trim" : { "trimName" : "cut2", "startTime" : "00:00:05", "endTime" : "00:00:15" } }
```

the error I get is

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 1 == 0
```

For technical reasons use the Id cannot be used for deleting.

Comment: i ran the same code and it works for me....do you get the messages you logging inside the delete callback? i.e. like "Removed the document"

Comment: That is very odd, I am not getting the "removed the document" message. I updated the question with the error I get

Comment: What specific versions of MongoDB server and driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I found the issue, I needed to parse the trimNametoDelete, stupid mistake, I was sending the trimNametoDelete as a string.

```
const deleteTrimByName = function (db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  const collection = db.collection(documentName)

  console.log('>>>>>' + trimNameToDelete)
  collection.deleteOne({Video_trim: JSON.parse(trimNameToDelete)}, function (err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null)
    assert.equal(1, result.result.n)
    console.log('Removed the document')
    callback(result)
  })
  fs.unlink('./public/videos/cut-videos/' + documentName + '/' + JSON.parse(trimNameToDelete).trimName + '.mp4', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('failed to delete local image:' + err)
    } else {
      console.log('successfully deleted local image')
    }
  })
}
```